# how to split and write values to new columns in node.js

Tags: node.js, excel, split, string-parsing

I have a column in excel with values like `AN;12.32:AD;14.52` So I need to split them into two new columns.
My code:

```
var ambIt = "AN;r12.32:AD;t14.52"`
var komIt = ambIt.split(":");
var ndmIt= komIt[0].split(";")
var uskIt= komIt[1].split(";")

console.log(uskIt[1]);
console.log(ndmIt[1]);
```

`

And its giving me exaclty how I want it to look. Any idea on how I can do that on a whole column in excel and write the values to new columns?

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Your Q: how I can do that on a whole column in excel?  Our Q: How exactly is NodeJS reading your Excel file?

Comment: I am not sure if I am getting your Q right. Using the fs and exceljs library...